# SQL Server pyodbc Driver issue: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error

Tags: sql-server, odbc, driver, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server Database using python with pyodbc on my Mac. The full error I get when I run is:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: collate_byname::collate_byname failed to construct for C/en_CA.

The Python code to connect using the driver is:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
                  "Server=simvo-dbs.database.windows.net,1433;"
                  "Database=degree-planner-db;"
                  "UID=simvo_admin@simvo-dbs;"
                  "PWD=McGill_514;"
                  "loginTimeout=30;")
```

Other Relevant Files:

odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

odbc.ini:

```
[MSSQL]
TDS_Version = 7.3
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server = simvo-dbs.database.windows.net
Port = 1433
```

Any idea on what the issue is will be greatly appreciated. I am using a MAC.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and there is no solution, as far as I can tell. But you can workaround it running the script like this:

```
env LANG=C python3 myscript.py
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring freetds.conf (mac: `/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf`) allows you to reference the DSN configuration in the connection string instead of passing in characters which cause errors.

If you add in the following to the bottom of the freetds.conf:

```
[mssql]
host = db-name.random-string.region.rds.amazonaws.com
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0 
client charset = UTF-8
```

And then you can pass in the DSN value in your connection string, which shouldn't cause any errors:

```
con_str = f"DSN=mssql,UID=username,PWD=XXXXXX"

con = pyodbc.connect(con_str) # shouldn't throw any errors
```

This information was adapted from this post: https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/wiki/Mac-setup-to-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I changed the settings to use ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, the error has gone away.